# How to add strings to already existing arrays in mongodb using Java

Tags: java, arrays, mongodb, minecraft, bukkit

How can I add a string to an already existing array in MongoDB using Java?

I am currently fixing up an old Minecraft permissions plugin of mine. Per player permissions do not work. They are unable to add to the array in profiles called permissions. Therefore I need to know how to add strings to that array. I am not a very experienced coder however would like to fix this old plugin of mine!

It currently succeeds in running the /profile addpermission command, however, does not add the permission to the array in MongoDB...

Current code: (Uses qLib)

The commands code:

```java
    @Command(names = {"profile addpermission"}, permission = "atmosphere.profile.admin")
    public static void profileAddPermission(CommandSender sender, @Param(name = "target") Profile target, @Param(name = "permission") String permission){
        if(target.hasPermissionPriorToLogin(permission.toLowerCase())){
            sender.sendMessage(BukkitChat.format("&cTarget already has access to the specified permission."));
            return;
        }
        sender.sendMessage(BukkitChat.format("&aAdded the permission &r" + permission.toLowerCase() + "&r &ato &r" + target.getDisplayName() + "&r&a's profile."));
        target.getPermissions().add(permission.toLowerCase());
        target.save();
    }
```

The .add after target.getPermissons: https://www.skyhcf.net/images/0xff1.png

The getPermissions code:

```java
    public List<String> getPermissions(){
        List<String> permissions = Lists.newArrayList();
        for(String perm : this.permissions){
            if(!permissions.contains(perm)) {
                permissions.add(perm);
            }
        }
        for(Grant grant : getActiveGrants()){
            for(String perm : grant.getRank().getPermissions()){
                if(!permissions.contains(perm)){
                    permissions.add(perm);
                }
            }
            for(Rank parent : grant.getRank().getParentsAsRanks()){
                for(String perm : parent.getPermissions()){
                    if(!permissions.contains(perm)) permissions.add(perm);
                }
            }
        }
        return permissions;
    }
```

Comment: Can you share the example of what is the end goal of this question?

Comment: Added some extra info in the original post.

Comment: @JackStanford - Go through [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit the question.

Comment: I edited the question a bit more.

Comment: but hwere is the code you use to actually save the permission? as you are saying you have issue with saving it to mongo, yet you didn't show any code related to saving it to mongo.

Comment: I'm not sure what code I should use to save the permission. That's all I'm asking.

I can do code + permission as permission is just the permission that the user inputs.